# Clickable images in QTextBrowser

Tags: python, image, pyqt5

I need to show original images by clicking the previews in QTextBrowser (PyQt5). Is it possible to make images in QTextBrowser clickable? Except href, because there must be a function. Simle html doesnt help:

```
for sub in sub_list:
    attachment_list.append('<img src="pic/thumbnails/thumb_%s" onclick="window.open("pic/serv_pics/%s")"> ' % (sub, sub))
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an empty 'a href' to html instead of 'onclick':

```
for sub in sub_list:
            attachment_list.append('<a href><img src="pic/thumbnails/thumb_%s" alt="Image is loading"></a>' % (sub))
```

Then inserted the following into my class:

```
self.textBrowser.anchorClicked.connect(self.function)
```

and defined a function. Seems to work.